# Addition of two 16bit numbers using base index addressing mode

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am facing issue in addition using base index addressing mode

```
MOV AX,0000H
MOV DS,AX
MOV AX, [4000H]
MOV BX, [4002H]
MOV CX, [BX+SI]
ADD AX,CX
MOV DI,4005H
MOV [DI],AX
HLT
```

Suppose Value in AX = 0A02 and BX = 0F02 then value of DI= 1904 because we are storing the AX value which changed when we have implemented addition in DX but I am getting an unexpected output the code adding the unexpected output here [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q37oQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose Value in AX = 0A02 and BX = 0F02 then value of DI= 1904

```
 0A02h
+0F02h
------
 1904h
```

Why do you think that `DI` equals the sum of `AX` and `BX`?
Nowhere in your code is there such an addition.

```
MOV AX, 0000H
MOV DS, AX

MOV AX, [4000H]                    -> AX=0A02
MOV BX, [4002H]                    -> BX=0F02
MOV CX, [BX+SI]    BX=0F02 SI=0000 -> CX=0000
ADD AX, CX         AX=0A02 CX=0000 -> AX=0A02

MOV DI, 4005H
MOV [DI], AX
```

Because the `SI` register contains 0, the instruction `MOV CX, [BX+SI]` is equivalent to `MOV CX, [BX]` and so will fetch the memory word at address [0F02h] (because `BX=0F02h`), which looking at the mem dump produces `CX=0`.

Hereafter the addition `ADD AX, CX` will not actually change the `AX` contents.
And so the final store will set the word at 4005h equal to 0A02h, exactly as is shown in the debugger.